# Open file is not read the text, Get_Next_Line.c

Tags: c

hello guys a just need help on this, not showing the text I wrote:
This program open the file and just show on command what is inside,
if buffer is > 0 show all the text contained in file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *ft_strncat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n)
{
if (n != 0) {
    char *d = dst;
    const char *s = src;
    while (*d != 0)
        d++;
    do {
        if ((*d = *s++) == 0)
            break;
        d++;
    } while (--n != 0);
    *d = 0;
}
return (dst);
}


char *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    char buffer[2] = "";
    char **line;

    if( !*line )
        *line = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

    *line[0] = '\0';

    while( read(fd, buffer, 1) > 0 ) {
        ft_strncat(*line, buffer, 1);
        if( buffer[0] == '\n' )
            break;
    }
    return (0);
}


int main(void)
{
    int     fd;
    int     ret;

    fd = open("ola.txt", O_RDONLY);

    if (fd < 3 && fd != 0)
        return (-1);

    printf("%d\n", fd);
    printf("%s\n", get_next_line(fd));
    return (0);
}
```

im trying to see the error but I cant, im a noob on C yet
thank you for help me.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `line` before you can read or write `*line`.

Comment: `line` should be a function parameter, not a local variable.

Comment: regarding: `char **line;

    if( !*line )
        *line = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));`  on the first entry into this loop, the pointer `line` could contain ANY value including pointing into memory that the application does not own,.  The result would be a seg fault event.  OT: regarding: `sizeof(char)`  This is defined in the C language as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: regarding: `char *get_next_line(int fd)`  This function always returns 0 (NULL) so the contents of the input file will never be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` should be `char *`, not `char **`. That would only be needed if it were a function parameter that should be updated by the function.

You need to return `line` from the function, not `0`.

You should use `realloc()` to grow `line` if the input line is longer than the size of `line`. Use a variable `capacity` to hold the current size.

There's no good reason to use `ft_strncat()`. Use another variable to hold the current position in `line`, and write the character there directly.

```
char *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    char buffer;
    size_t capacity = 100;
    char *line = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
    size_t pos = 0;

    *line[0] = '\0';

    while( read(fd, &buffer, 1) > 0 ) {
        if (pos > capacity - 2) {
            capacity += 100;
            line = realloc(line, capacity);
        }
        line[pos++] = buffer;
        if( buffer == '\n' ) {
            line[pos] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

In addition, the caller should assign the result to a variable, so it can free the memory. Otherwise you'll create lots of memory leaks when you read all the lines of the file.